# altering cv in latex - tabular extending two pages?

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I have the following script for writing an academic cv:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\title{\bfseries\Huge Name}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%
%
\section*{Personal Details}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
\hline
Address: & blah blah blah\\
& blah\\
& blah\vspace{5pt}\\
Phone: & +44 123 245676\vspace{5pt}\\
Email: & emailAdreSS.com 
\end{tabular}
%
%
\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
\hline\\
2011--present & PhD, Somewhere\vspace{5pt}\\
2010--2011 & MSc, Somewhere else\vspace{5pt}\\
2007--2010 & BSc, Some other place
\end{tabular}
%
%
\section*{Research Experience}


%
%
\section*{Scholarships and Awards}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
\hline\\
Sept. 2007 & \\
Sept. 2010 & \\
Oct. 2011 & 
\end{tabular}
%
%
\section*{Additional experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
\hline\\
&\textbullet Driving License, Full Clean\\
\end{tabular}
%
%
\section*{Referee}
\end{document}
```

The only problem that I am experiencing is how to write the section on Research Experience. For this I require the year on the left column (i.e. same as other sections) but I would like a paragraph on the right where I can provide a description of the tasks undertaken. What would be the best way of doing this? Keeping in mind that the section will probably extend to the second page.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace `tabular` by `longtable` as

```
\section*{Scholarships and Awards}
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
\hline\\
Sept. 2007 & \lipsum[1] \\
Sept. 2010 & \lipsum[2] \\
Oct. 2011 & \lipsum[3]
\end{longtable}
```

The full MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\title{\bfseries\Huge Name}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%
%
\section*{Personal Details}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
\hline
Address: & blah blah blah\\
& blah\\
& blah\vspace{5pt}\\
Phone: & +44 123 245676\vspace{5pt}\\
Email: & emailAdreSS.com
\end{tabular}
%
%
\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
\hline\\
2011--present & PhD, Somewhere\vspace{5pt}\\
2010--2011 & MSc, Somewhere else\vspace{5pt}\\
2007--2010 & BSc, Some other place
\end{tabular}
%
%
\section*{Research Experience}


%
%
\section*{Scholarships and Awards}
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
\hline\\
Sept. 2007 & \lipsum[1] \\
Sept. 2010 & \lipsum[2] \\
Oct. 2011 & \lipsum[3]
\end{longtable}
%
%
\section*{Additional experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
\hline\\
&\textbullet Driving License, Full Clean\\
\end{tabular}
%
%
\section*{Referee}
\end{document}
```